# Post-processing/volume not reflecting in other camera

Tags: unity-game-engine

**Heads-up, I'm using the built-in Unity volume profile instead of Post-Processing V2!**

Hey everyone. I'm currently stuck trying to figure out how to make both my cameras produce the same post-processing effect. Right now, I've managed to create the effect I want in my main camera which is being displayed properly in the build but not in my other camera which is the spawned third-person view of the human model.

Left is the human's camera, right is the main camera aka the cat's pov. As you can see, there is a difference between post-processing effects in both cameras. Both cameras also have the Enable Post-Processing check ticked and set to global.

[image]

Currently, I have the cat and human's camera disabled and activated when it spawns into the game. I also have attached a child object to the both cameras containing the volume profile.

This is my volume profile in case you need more context.

[image]

And this is where I've attached the volume profile to.

[image]

Would appreciate any help I can get! Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a Postprocess Volume, its really easy to do. Just go on to both cameras and add Postprocessing layers to them, and don't forget to enable post processing in the camera options if you are using URP. Then just go on to Post-Processing-Volume-Layer in the just added component and select 'Everything'. This should do the Job! Hope it helps.

Here, you can also look at this: https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/PostProcessing-Stack-SetUp.html

Comment: hey! unfortunately, it didn't work for me since i'm using unity's global volume and not the post-processing stack package. i've edited the post above to give you more context on how i post-process my stuff :)

Comment: Make sure that you have enabled Post Processing on BOTH cameras, since you're using URP you always need to enable that in your camera options. Try that hope it helps :)

Comment: Bingo! My spawned clone had the Enable Post-Processing box unchecked despite my prefab having it ticked which was weird to begin with. Gonna try to figure that problem out but thanks for the help, Flof!

Comment: Im happy it worked, this is a very common issue, that the post processing is disabled on the Camera. Im not even sure why this even is a option but uh yea.